# External API query: Is my password visible to the user?

Tags: php, api, passwords

I have a website that contains a user input field in a GET form. When the user hits a "search button" the text from the input field is combined with a password (stored in a separate php file) to query an external API.

```
@file_get_contents(MyURL)
```

Where MyURL contains the text input and the confidential password.

Question: Is the password visible in the browser network? If yes, where? How can I see that in e. g. chrome?

But the most important question: If the password is visible, how can I hide it?

Thanks!
Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST could be better as POST body is not usually saved in logs or it is not cached by proxy, etc... while GET parameters (being in the URL) are.

The password is not visible by the user, as said, but if $MyUrl is not HTTPS, it goes in cleartext, which means you **must** assume MyUrl is compromised. If it is HTTP, even if the user cannot directly see it, someone else in a better position in the network will, soon or later.

Comment: thx for info. Do you think it is sufficient if $MyUrl is https oder does the website (my homepage), that is doing the call, as well need https. $MyUrl is the URL of the external API service which is luckily supporting https

Comment: If you are definitely sure the website will not contact you back later with any data linked to these credentials (i.e. the credentials or a session id or a token, etc...), you can have your site HTTP and MyURL HTTPS. Every time MyURL needs to send anything to you, and it **opens** the connection, data will be in cleartext. When you open the connection to MyURL and it replies with data (as in a normal TCP case) it will be encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

The password won't be visible by the user, as the request is done between your server and the API. It does not transit through the end user web browser.

```
browser --(input text)--> your server --(input text + password)--> API
```

Instead of using file_get_content you probably should use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make the http request. You would have a better control on the request options.

Comment: Thanks! This is interesting since the first comment to my question was, that my solution is unsafe and I should use a POST method. Was he wrong? (The comment seems to be deleted now)

Comment: He was wrong if he said that the password was visible ; but using https and a POST method is the right way of doing a request containing a password, and he was right on this point.